# How to pass the value and get the value from another page via routerlink in angular4?

Tags: angular, authentication, angular4-router

I want to pass a value with URL using `routerLink` and read that value on another page. Like I have Modules and Submodules. On select of first record the id of that record pass to User page. After read that Userid I want to show detail of that User and modules/submodules.

So How can I pass and get the Values(object)?

Userdetails Component class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'userdetail',
  templateUrl: './userdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userdetail.component.css']
})
export class UserdetailComponent implements OnInit {

  username: any;
   moduleid: any;
 submoduleid: any;
 login: any;

 constructor(private _route:ActivatedRoute){}
ngOnInit() {
 this._route.params.subscribe(params => {

   this.username = params['moduleid']

 }); 
}
}
```

Login Component class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Userslogin } from 'app/users/userslogin';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserloginService } from 'app/userlogin/userlogin.service';
import { User } from 'app/userlogin/user';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm: FormGroup;

  user = new User;

 login: any;
 modules=[];
 module: any;
 usernam: any;
 pass: any;
 moduleid: any;
 submoduleid: any;

 submitted = false;

  i; j;

  constructor(private editionService: UserloginService, private router: Router) {

    const username = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    const password = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      username: username,
      password: password
    });
}

   ngOnInit() {

  }



  loginuser() { 
    this.usernam = this.myForm.get('username').value; 
    this.pass = this.myForm.get('password').value; 
    this.editionService.getlogin(this.usernam, this.pass ).subscribe(
    login => this.login = login); 
    this.moduleid = this.login[0].moduleid; 




    if(this.login != null){ 
        this.router.navigate(['userlogin/userdetail', this.moduleid] ); 
     } 

     else { 
       alert('Click login') 
      }    

    }



  }
```

Router:

```
export const UserloginRoutes: Routes =[{
    path: '',
        children: [
           {path: 'login',
                component:LoginComponent,
                },
       {path:'userdetail/:moduleid', component: UserdetailComponent}
        ]}]
```

Comment: Please update your question along with whole requirement.

Comment: Once i click the login.. if username and password matched then the redirect the another page with the userid, moduleid and submoduleid.

Comment: I get the one object from backend contains moduleid and submoduleid. I stored that object in frontend var login.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**: You can send value in parameters as:
In Route.ts

```
{ path: 'user/:user', component: UserComponent},
```

In Login Component

```
 this.router.navigate(['/user',loginInfo]);  //loginInfo is data you want to send
```

In user component

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router:Router, private _route: ActivatedRoute)

  ngOnInit() {
      this._route.params.subscribe((params)=>{
       console.log(params)
      })
}
```

**Method 2**: Using shared service

Create a shared.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    private user= new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

    currentDetail = this.user.asObservable();
    setUser(user?: any) {
        this.user.next(user);
    }
}
```

Send your value using shared service from **Login component**

```
  this.sharedService.setUser(obj)
```

In your **User component** get your value as

```
this.sharedService.currentDetail .subscribe(detail=>{
      console.log(detail)  //detail is data you send in shared service
       })
```

**Method 3**:

You know how to work with **cookies**

Comment: how to pass the login values to another page?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this doc: https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero .

You can send id param in your route which can then be read from paramMap:

```
this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        // (+) before `params.get()` turns the string into a number
        this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
        // Use selectionId now
      });
```

Comment: Thanks...       how to display each user different login user modules/submodules using our userid?

Comment: loginuser() {
 
    this.usernam = this.myForm.get('username').value;
    this.pass = this.myForm.get('password').value;
   
    this.editionService.getlogin(this.usernam, this.pass ).subscribe(login => this.login = login);

    //this.modules = this.login[0];

    //this.module = this.modules[0];

      alert(this.login);

      //alert(this.modules);

     // alert(this.module);

          if(this.login != null){

            this.router.navigate(['doctor/doctorlist']);

            }

         else {
              alert('Click login')
            }}

Answer (score 0):

You can send data as **Route paramater**.Firstly you need to create a route like:

```
{path:'userdetail/:userid/:moduleid/:submoduleid',component:UserDetailComponent}
```

Then in your login function you can you can redirect to userdetail component by passing all data:

```
loginuser() { 
this.username = this.myForm.get('username').value; 
this.pass = this.myForm.get('password').value; 
this.editionService.getlogin(this.username, this.pass ).subscribe(
login => this.login = login); 
this.moduleid = this.login[0].moduleid; 
this.submoduleid = this.login[0].submoduleid; 
this.userid = this.userid
alert(this.login);  
if(this.login != null){ 
    this.router.navigate(['/userdetail',this.userid, this.moduleid, this.submoduleid]); 
 } else { alert('Click login') }
}
```

Now in your UserDetailComponent you can fetch route parameters as:

```
constructor(private _route:ActivatedRoute){}
ngOnInit() {
this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.userid = params['userid']
  this.moduleid = params['moduleid']
  this.submoduleid = params['submoduleid']
}); 
}
```

Comment: i got this errorERROR 404
Page not found :(
Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist. Take me home

Comment: once i click the login button.. it shows the error.... but i click the login button without passing parameters in routerlink..it doesnot shows error

Comment: will you please add the component html and class in your question

Comment: You have to pass the parameter inside the array. `this.router.navigate(['userlogin/userdetail', this.usernam] );`

Comment: Once i pass the login value in routerlink.. it doesnot open and it redirect to homepage.. How to pass the login value to another page.. login value have moduleid and submoduleid like 1,1 in list object

Comment: yes.. once i pass the username its working.. but i pass the login value to another page..its not working

Comment: loginuser() { 
    this.usernam = this.myForm.get('username').value; 
    this.pass = this.myForm.get('password').value; 
    this.editionService.getlogin(this.usernam, this.pass ).subscribe(
    login => this.login = login); 
    //this.moduleid = this.login[0].moduleid; 
    //this.submoduleid = this.login[0].submoduleid; 
    //this.userid = this.userid
    //alert(this.moduleid);  
   
    if(this.login != null){ 
        this.router.navigate(['userlogin/userdetail', this.login] ); 
     } 
    
     else { 
       alert('Click login') 
      }    

    }

Comment: You can extract value of moduleid and submoduleid from login variable and then send it in url as shown above.

Comment: It is specified in my answer. `this.moduleid = this.login[0].moduleid; this.submoduleid = this.login[0].submoduleid;` and then send them as i shown in my answer.

Comment: once i pass the this.moduleid...  The page is redirect to homepage..not redirect to userdetail  page

Comment: Are you getting any value inside `this.moduleid`.Try printing it in console.

Comment: i am not get any value once i console the moduleid... but i console the login..i get  [Array(2)]0: (2) [1, 1]length: 1__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Then the problem is in accessing `moduleid` value from login object.There is no problem in your navigation part.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ankita...How to access the moduleid value from login object??

Comment: I don't know the structure of your login object.

Comment: from backend i get the login object value  is [1,1]

Comment: If its an array consisting just 2 values then access directly as `this.moduleid=login[0]`

Comment: write it inside your if condition.`if(this.login != null){ this.moduleid=login[0]}`

Comment: How to pass the login object in routerlink??

Comment: No.. How to pass the login object in routerlink??

Comment: Where you want to use routerLink here?

Comment: How to pass the login obejct  in router link?.. once i try to pass the login object it shows the 404 error

Comment: Can you show me how are you passing it in routerLink?

Comment: this.router.navigate(['userlogin/userdetail', this.login]);

Comment: RouterLink is a directive and is used in Component template.This is not routerLink.And you can not pass whole object in navigate function.First you will need to extract moduleId and submoduleId from login object and send them individually.

Comment: well... i pass the moduleid individually as above.. it shows cannot not read the moduleid error and page redirect to home..not userdetail

Comment: how to pass moduleid and submoduleid individually from login object in routerlink

Comment: How to create session login and logout in angular4?