# Angular 5 communicating between components through service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

i am working on an Angular 5 application and i have an API that store my data. The thing is i have two components, one for displaying data and one for posting data.

They both interact with the API through a service with two functions:

```
addCandidate(candidate: Candidate): Observable<Candidate> {
  this.candidatesList.next(this.http.get(this.apiUrl));
  return this.http.post<Candidate>(this.apiUrl, candidate, httpOptions);
} 

listCandidates(): Observable<Candidate[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).map(res => <Candidate[]>res);
}
```

The components have methods for subscribing to the service:

```
saveCandidate(): void {
  if(this.candidate.skills.indexOf(', ') >= 0) {
    this.candidate.skills = (<string>this.candidate.skills).split(', '); 
  }
  this.candidatesService.addCandidate(this.candidate).subscribe();
}
```

And respectively ( this one is on init ) :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.candidatesService.listCandidates().subscribe(candidates => this.candidates = candidates);
}
```

So, hence i can't really know when the api is updated, i want to update the list after saveCandidate() method takes action.

**How does one update one component with new api data after another submitted to the servic?.**

*Side note: i tried using rxjs Subject.asObservable().next(..the http request). But Observable.next is not a method. Maybe i misused them.*

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48902022/6808483

Comment: I have given a similar example here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49007399/changes-done-in-one-component-view-doesnt-reflect-in-another-component-view-in/49008521#49008521

Comment: Have a look on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760281/how-to-pass-the-value-and-get-the-value-from-another-page-via-routerlink-in-angu/48760344#48760344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you tried (i.e, `Subject`) is the correct way to approach this problem.

Use [this link](http://www.iamnotanengineer.com/2017/angular-4-what-is-a-subject-and-how-it-can-be-used-basic-example/) for improving your understanding on `Subject` and follow these points:

1. Declare the subject in the service
2. In the component where you are posting data, make the subject emit an event with a string value (let's say, `'Data Changed'`) using the code `this.candidatesService.mySubject.next('Data Changed')`.
3. Subscribe to this `Subject` in the component where you are listing the data and call your service method to `get` your data inside the subscribe method like this:

   `this.candidatesService.mySubject.subscribe((value) => {
          this.candidatesService.listCandidates().subscribe(candidates => 
          this.candidates = candidates);
    });`

   This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to have been it.Guess i have much to learn on angular.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service with a BehaviorSubject that will store the state object, e.g. a collection of candidates. One component will use next() on the subject to add the candidate, and another will subscribe to get the current list of candidates. 
I recorded a 20-min video that can help you in understanding how this can be implemented: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYNEH_k0e_4